# keycloak-angular interceptor not sending authorization header

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, keycloak-angular

I'm trying to integrate  keycloak-angular in my angular application.
The authentication flow works well, however when I make a request to my django api I get a 403. The HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header is missing and I don't understand why. When I hardcoded a header in my http service it worked.

This is the library:

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular

This is my keycloak config

```
// utility/app.init.ts
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';


export function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService): () => Promise<boolean> {
  return () =>
    keycloak.init({
      config: {
        url: 'http://sso.portal.ca/auth',
        realm: 'kedi',
        clientId: 'account'
      },
      
      bearerPrefix: 'Bearer',
      initOptions: {
          onLoad: 'login-required', // redirects to the login page
          checkLoginIframe: true,
          checkLoginIframeInterval: 1000
      }
    });
}
```

This is my app module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CoreModule } from './@core/core.module';
import { ThemeModule } from './@theme/theme.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import {
  NbChatModule,
  NbDatepickerModule,
  NbDialogModule,
  NbMenuModule,
  NbSidebarModule,
  NbToastrModule,
  NbWindowModule,
} from '@nebular/theme';
import { KeycloakAngularModule, KeycloakService, KeycloakBearerInterceptor } from 'keycloak-angular';
import { initializeKeycloak} from '../app/utility/app.init'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NbSidebarModule.forRoot(),
    NbMenuModule.forRoot(),
    NbDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    NbDialogModule.forRoot(),
    NbWindowModule.forRoot(),
    NbToastrModule.forRoot(),
    CoreModule.forRoot(),
    ThemeModule.forRoot(),
    KeycloakAngularModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
      multi: true,
      deps: [KeycloakService]
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: KeycloakBearerInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

And this is my api service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {
  HttpClient,
  HttpHeaders,
  HttpErrorResponse,
} from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PortalService {
  // change later
  apiUrl: string = 'http://api.portal.ca/public';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUrl(uri: string) {
    return `${this.apiUrl}/${uri}`;
  }
  
  getPartnersTableStructure() {
    return this.http.get(this.getUrl('partner/table_config/'));
  }

  getPartners() {
    return this.http.get(this.getUrl('partner'));
  }

  getEDIDocuments() {
    return this.http.get(this.getUrl('edi_document'));
  }

  getEDIDocumentsTableStructure() {
    return this.http.get(this.getUrl('edi_document/table_config'));
  }
}
```

Let me know if more info is needed thanks

Comment: Your config seems to be OK. Can you check if the user has all the necessary roles set?

Comment: user has all the necessary roles, I don't see the token nowhere though, looked at cookies and localstorage, thats weird

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was missing the `silent-check-sso.html`

when I added the file it just started to work

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      parent.postMessage(location.href, location.origin);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems you’re missing a configuration line, take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular#httpclient-interceptor. enableBearerInterceptor: true which will add the interceptor for you.

I don’t know if you even need that line because it’s active by default.

*Another issue could be that* (would need some insight into the code , but this is purely on speculation) if the token was not added in module/submodules where HttpClient requests were made then it would not been adding the token in http call.

Comment: I exactly have the situation where the token is added to requests made via services which are provided in root but it is not if they belong to any of the sub-modules. Do you know why this is and how to solve it?